# Changing coord ref in rasters using terra

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, terra

I'm trying to change from LON/LAT to UTM.

For example, any of these rasters (https://envicloud.wsl.ch/#/?prefix=chelsa%2Fchelsa_V2%2FGLOBAL%2F). I cropped Europe and I don't know how to proceed using the function "project".

The original coord ref is lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

I don't know what UTM zone/ETSR/EPSG/WGS I need to specify to get UTM coordinates.

```
eur_UTM <- project(eur, "???")
```

Comment: You need to know what UTM zone your data is in before you can define the EPSG. Here is an interactive map to figure it out, just keep in mind when searching for the EPSG code, that the equator defines N/S division so there is a UTM 16N and 16S which are different EPSG codes. Over large areas there may be multiple UTM zones, in which case you should use a different projection. Also, be mindful of the transformation used in terra::project (eg., "near" is for nominal data, "bilinear" for continuous) https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-#

Answer (score 1):

You cannot accurately use UTM for all of Europe. You can only use one UTM zone at a time. UTM zones have a width of 6 degrees longitude (~600 km) and Europe is much wider.

You could use take a longitude for central Europe (let's say 15 degrees) and compute the zone

```
ceiling((180+15)/6)
#[1] 33
```

And use this crs: `"proj=utm +zone=33"`

But that would not be appropriate as you would have tremendous distortion at the E and W edges of your data.

There are map projections that are suitable for Europe. However, as you do not motivate your question we cannot help you much. Perhaps you can edit your question to clarify your goal. (why do you want to use UTM in the first place?)